# Concerns with Seeding Data in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, seeding

please I have a question regarding this link on Microsoft site where example of how to seed data is given:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1

While seeding the data, Members are not assigned any ID and in the Member model, [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] annotation had been used which means we are going to be inputting the datavalue for the ID ourselves. So, how will the application knows which member matches which memberid (foreign key) in the enrollment entity.

Comment: I think i figure out the answer. [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] annotation is not indicated in the Student Entity. So, it will auto generate the number itself. Does it mean the autogeneration starts from figure 1 ?

Comment: A class object in the constructor sets properties to a default value.  If you need a different value you need a constructor to set the value.

Comment: @jdweng The class context in the tutorial is SchoolContext and there is nowhere where the property is set to a default value or does it mean 1 comes out of the box as the start value for the default value. Let us say I want a different value, for instance, I want the figure to start from 100, how do i achieve this please.

Comment: Please read the [Data Seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) section of the official EF Core documentation. You have to provide explicit primary and foreign key values regardless of whether they normally are auto generated or not.

Comment: A class property will have a default value like int are set to zero and string is set to an empty string.  Ivan's link sets properties to values other than the default constructor value.

Answer (score 0):

if you ask about how show relation in EF Model, please look at this sample :

```
    [Table("AppUserInRole")]
    public partial class AppUserInRole
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public short RoleId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(RoleId))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(AppRole.AppUserInRoles))]
        public virtual AppRole Role { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(AppUserInfo.AppUserInRoles))]
        public virtual AppUserInfo User { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

in this sample we have 3 table and 3 model for them.
AppUserInRole has relation with AppUserInfo and AppRole.